# Scrollable sidebar div issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have a main content part of a sidebar that is supposed to be scrollable if it overflows. The problem is that it makes the whole page scroll instead of just the sidebar. The other problem is that it's supposed to scroll inside of it's container instead of making the whole sidebar scroll.

How do I fix this?

it's supposed to look like this:

```
___

header
___
nav pill 1 
nav pill 2
___
a href image
a href image   
...  
...
___
button  
text
___
```

```js
const tooltipTriggerList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]')
const tooltipList = [...tooltipTriggerList].map(tooltipTriggerEl => new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl))

window.onload = (event) => {
    const tooltip = bootstrap.Tooltip.getInstance('#add_bot_button') // Returns a Bootstrap tooltip instance
    tooltip.show();
};

document.getElementById('server_wide_button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById('channel_specific_button').classList.remove('active');
    document.getElementById('server_wide_button').classList.add('active');
});

document.getElementById('channel_specific_button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById('server_wide_button').classList.remove('active');
    document.getElementById('channel_specific_button').classList.add('active');
});

document.getElementById('add_bot_button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('adding bot to guild');
});
```

```css
#sidebar_header {
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    width: inherit;
}

#sidebar_sub_header {
    /* top: 0; */
    /* position: fixed;
    width: inherit; */
}

#sidebar_main_content {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#sidebar_footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0; 
    width: inherit;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 250px;

    min-height: 100vh;
    max-height: 100vh;
}

/* #sidebar_main_content::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
} */

#dropdown {
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- <div class="col align-items-start bg-dark text-white"> -->
        <div class="align-items-start text-center p-0 bg-dark text-white" id="sidebar">
            <div class="p-3 bg-dark text-white" id="sidebar_header">
                <span class="fs-4">
                    Header
                </span>

                <hr>

                <div class="p-3" id="sidebar_sub_header bg-secondary">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white active" aria-current="page" id="server_wide_button">
                                Test 1
                            </a>
                        </li>
    
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white" id="channel_specific_button">
                                Test 2
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- <div class="p-3" id="sidebar_sub_header bg-secondary">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white active" aria-current="page" id="server_wide_button">
                            Test 1
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white" id="channel_specific_button">
                            Test 2
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div> -->

            <div class="mb-auto p-3 bg-danger flex-fill" id="sidebar_main_content">
                <!-- main content - scrollable -->

                <ul class="nav flex-column mb-auto align-items-center">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right" data-bs-title="test tooltip">
                        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/02/10/11/12/smiley-4836191_1280.png" class="rounded-circle" style="height:100px;width:100px">
                    </a>
                </li>
        
                <br>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right" data-bs-title="test tooltip">
                        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/02/10/11/12/smiley-4836191_1280.png" class="rounded-circle" style="height:100px;width:100px">
                    </a>
                </li>
        
                <br>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right" data-bs-title="test tooltip">
                        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/02/10/11/12/smiley-4836191_1280.png" class="rounded-circle" style="height:100px;width:100px">
                    </a>
                </li>
        
                <br>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right" data-bs-title="test tooltip">
                        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/02/10/11/12/smiley-4836191_1280.png" class="rounded-circle" style="height:100px;width:100px">
                    </a>
                </li>
        
                <br>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right" data-bs-title="test tooltip">
                        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/02/10/11/12/smiley-4836191_1280.png" class="rounded-circle" style="height:100px;width:100px">
                    </a>
                </li>
        
                <br>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right" data-bs-title="test tooltip">
                        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/02/10/11/12/smiley-4836191_1280.png" class="rounded-circle" style="height:100px;width:100px">
                    </a>
                </li>
        
                <br>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right" data-bs-title="test tooltip">
                        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/02/10/11/12/smiley-4836191_1280.png" class="rounded-circle" style="height:100px;width:100px">
                    </a>
                </li>
        
                <br>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right" data-bs-title="test tooltip">
                        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/02/10/11/12/smiley-4836191_1280.png" class="rounded-circle" style="height:100px;width:100px">
                    </a>
                </li>
        
                <br>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right" data-bs-title="test tooltip">
                        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/02/10/11/12/smiley-4836191_1280.png" class="rounded-circle" style="height:100px;width:100px">
                    </a>
                </li>
        
                <br>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right" data-bs-title="test tooltip">
                        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/02/10/11/12/smiley-4836191_1280.png" class="rounded-circle" style="height:100px;width:100px">
                    </a>
                </li>
        
                <br>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right" data-bs-title="test tooltip">
                        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/02/10/11/12/smiley-4836191_1280.png" class="rounded-circle" style="height:100px;width:100px">
                    </a>
                </li>
        
                <br>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="p-3 bg-dark text-white" id="sidebar_footer">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="add_bot_button" role="button" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" data-bs-title="Test tooltip">
                    Test Button
                </a>
            
                <br><br>
                
                <div class="dropup-center dropup">
                    <a href="#" class="align-items-center text-white text-decoration-none dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownUser1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        {{ wallet_address }}
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark text-small shadow" aria-labelledby="dropdownUser1">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delete User Info</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col bg-secondary text-white" id="main_content">
            One of three columns
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using bootstrap 5.3.0 alpha1

Also - is what I have right so far? Each element is supposed to be fixed in the sidebar. not sure if i need position: fixed for each element or just for the sidebar. any help would be appreciated

edit:
also where `test text here 0000000000000000000000000` is, how do i shrink that or confine it inside the div?

edit2: edited code to show some updates

Answer (score 0):

#### Set different overflow behaviours for the 3 containers

You want the *outer* container *not* to scroll. That is important, because if you don't specifically block scrolling of the outer container, it will scroll. That was the cause of your problem.

Then you want the sidebar itself to scroll, and the main content to (separately) scroll.

I have added to your code 3 `style` attributes, one for each of the 3 containers. I see you are carefully using classes, which is excellent: just put those styles into the relevant classes (I couldn't find the class for the main body text).

```css
#sidebar_header {
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#sidebar_sub_header {
  /* position: fixed; */
  /* width: inherit; */
}

#sidebar_main_content {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#sidebar_footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: inherit;
}

#sidebar {
  width: 250px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/dashboard_test.css') }}" />



<div class="container-fluid" style="height:100%; overflow:hidden;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="align-items-start text-center p-0 bg-dark text-white" id="sidebar" >
      <div class="p-3">
        <span class="fs-4" id="sidebar_heading">
                    Header
                </span>
      </div>

      <hr>

      <div class="p-3" id="sidebar_sub_header">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link active" aria-current="page">
                            Test 1
                        </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white">
                            Test 2
                        </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <hr>

      <div class="mb-auto p-3 bg-danger flex-fill" id="sidebar_main_content" style="height:100%;   overflow-y: scroll;">
        <!-- main content - scrollable -->

        <ul class="nav flex-column mb-auto align-items-center">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right" data-bs-title="test tooltip">
              <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/02/10/11/12/smiley-4836191_1280.png" class="rounded-circle" style="height:100px;width:100px">
            </a>
          </li>

          <br>

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right" data-bs-title="test tooltip">
              <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/02/10/11/12/smiley-4836191_1280.png" class="rounded-circle" style="height:100px;width:100px">
            </a>
          </li>

          <br>

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right" data-bs-title="test tooltip">
              <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/02/10/11/12/smiley-4836191_1280.png" class="rounded-circle" style="height:100px;width:100px">
            </a>
          </li>

          <br>

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right" data-bs-title="test tooltip">
              <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/02/10/11/12/smiley-4836191_1280.png" class="rounded-circle" style="height:100px;width:100px">
            </a>
          </li>

          <br>

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right" data-bs-title="test tooltip">
              <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/02/10/11/12/smiley-4836191_1280.png" class="rounded-circle" style="height:100px;width:100px">
            </a>
          </li>

          <br>

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right" data-bs-title="test tooltip">
              <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/02/10/11/12/smiley-4836191_1280.png" class="rounded-circle" style="height:100px;width:100px">
            </a>
          </li>

          <br>

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right" data-bs-title="test tooltip">
              <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/02/10/11/12/smiley-4836191_1280.png" class="rounded-circle" style="height:100px;width:100px">
            </a>
          </li>

          <br>

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right" data-bs-title="test tooltip">
              <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/02/10/11/12/smiley-4836191_1280.png" class="rounded-circle" style="height:100px;width:100px">
            </a>
          </li>

          <br>

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right" data-bs-title="test tooltip">
              <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/02/10/11/12/smiley-4836191_1280.png" class="rounded-circle" style="height:100px;width:100px">
            </a>
          </li>

          <br>

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right" data-bs-title="test tooltip">
              <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/02/10/11/12/smiley-4836191_1280.png" class="rounded-circle" style="height:100px;width:100px">
            </a>
          </li>

          <br>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="p-3" id="sidebar_footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="add_bot_button" role="button" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" data-bs-title="Test tooltip">
                    Test Button
                </a>

        <br><br>

        <div class="dropup-center dropup">
          <a href="#" class="d-flex align-items-center text-white text-decoration-none dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownUser1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        test text here 0000000000000000000000000
                    </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark text-small shadow" aria-labelledby="dropdownUser1">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delete User Info</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Logout</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col bg-secondary text-white" id="main_content">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: edited op to show updates - per the scrolling, trying to make only the main content ofr the sidebar (the image part) scrollable, not the sidebar + sidebar main content.

Comment: It is unclear what you are saying. Your term "Sidebar" seems to sometimes mean the left column, and sometimes mean the _whole_ of the output. I _think_ what you are now indicating is that you only want the _left_ part of the output (entitled, confusingly, "Header") to scroll, and not the right part of the output (entitled, for some reason "One of three columns"). I have removed the overflow-y:scroll on the right part. Please accept answer if it resolves your issue, or rewrite the question using unambiguous terminology such as "Left column"/"Right column", and use those terms in the code itself

Comment: both the sidebar - the left column - and the main body - the right column - are not supposed to scroll. what I'm looking at making scroll is this div (id="sidebar_main_content"). that's what i'm referring to when i say the sidebar main content. the sidebar header, just like the footer, should be fixed and only the sidebar main content should be scrolling if it happens to overflow. i hope this clears it up.

Comment: OK I think I understand better now. I have updated the code. Does this do what you want?